# Rails / I18n: How to translate constants of model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, translation, constants, rails-i18n

If I have a model with constants like

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS_DISABLED = 0
  STATUS_ENABLED  = 1
end
```

What can I do to translate it with locales?
I would like to do something like that:

```
en:
 Topic:
   STATUS_ENABLED: 'Enable'
   STATUS_DISABLED: 'Disable'
```

What is the best way to translate my models' constants?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Your YAML files have no access to Ruby-level constants, they're two different languages.

Further, you shouldn't. Constants are for use in your source-code. They have no need to be translated, you might as well ask how to localize class names.

If you want to map your symbolic constants to translatable strings, you should add a function that returns the English (or other native language) version, and then translate *that*.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS_DISABLED = 0
  STATUS_ENABLED  = 1

  def status_name(status)
    case status
    when CASE_DISABLED then 'disabled'
    when CASE_ENABLED then 'enabled'
    end
  end
end
```

Your YAML file would contain:

```
en:
  topic:
    enabled: 'Enable'
    disable: 'Disable'
```

If you have *many* values that you want to store as integers but translate to strings, you're probably after an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
class Topic
  enum status: [:disabled, :enabled]
end
```

This gives you access to `Topic.statuses` which will return `[:disabled, :enabled]`; you can invoke `to_s` on these symbols to produce the strings `'disabled'` and `'enabled'`, which you can feed into I18n to translate.

Comment: It's realy borring to do this for EACH CONSTANT. No trick here? :'(

Comment: No, again, the issue is that you're trying to translate constants. You really shouldn't be. Constants are an element of source code, they shouldn't need to be translated. If you have a bunch of things that you want to store as constants and translate, you should use an `enum`.

Comment: Can you show me the same exemple but with enum context? plz.

Comment: ok, but we lost the tenet of CONSTANT: I need to put value "0" and "1" in BD for exemple. `def enable? status == STATUS_ENABLE end` etc...

Comment: @Matrix Well, you can't. You can't have this both ways. Either do things the *Ruby* and *Rails* way and use symbols with `enum`, or don't.

Comment: @Matrix Ruby is one of the most powerful and expressive languages in existence. You keep coming up against problems with it because you invent solutions without knowing anything about Ruby or Rails, and you want to use *your solution* at any cost, rather than actually working with what the language provides. The fault here is with you, not Ruby.